# How to make a maintainable list of conditions

Tags: javascript

I have this code, which in time could be hard to read and maintain - numbers could come and go. How do I make this into an easy accessible maintainable list of conditions? Should I use an Array or something else?

```
var cs = 123456; //Some integer

if (cs >= 320000 
    && cs <= 320026 
    || cs == 320141 
    || cs == 320143 
    || cs == 320145 
    || cs == 320147 
    || cs == 320149 
    || cs == 320151) {

    new = 'Y';

} else if (cs >= 320100 
    && cs <= 320112 
    || cs >= 320114 
    && cs <= 320116 
    || cs >= 320123 
    && cs <= 320128 
    || cs == 320142 
    || cs == 320144 
    || cs == 320146 
    || cs == 320148 
    || cs == 320150 
    || cs == 320152) {

    new = 'N';

} else {

    new = 'Unknown';
};
```

Comment: You have greater and equal than, less and equal than, and equal to conditions on the same test that make hard to change into something else your tests.

Comment: I know, but I need to check ranges as well. Is there an easier or better way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, what you need is a `array` and an `indexOf` method.

Example:

```
if (cs >= 320000 && cs <= 320026  || $.inArray(value, valuesarray) > -1) {
 --
}
```

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16910305/if-or-shorter-way/16910313#16910313

Comment: Okay, so if I have ranges with "less than" and "greater than" then they should be kept out of the array, so that it only contain the exact numbers?

Comment: Yes,AFAIK solution is like that :)